# Any does array.method get error on typescript?

Tags: typescript

```
Question: This function determines if all the elements in array are subset of each other 


// SECTION Toy_03
Array.prototype.isSubsetOf = function (array: string[]): boolean {
  if (!array.length) return true;
    return this.every((el: string): boolean => array.includes(el));

example output// 
let a = ['commit', 'push'];
a.isSubsetOf(['commit', 'rebase', 'push', 'blame']); // true
};
```

I am converting couple of my javascript code into typescript in order to practice typescript.
I am assuming I am doing everything correct since all the array I am supposed to receive through this function is array of string and that it should return boolean value.

Then I get two erros like below:

inSubsetOf : Property 'isSubsetOf' does not exist on type 'any[]'.ts(2339)

includes : Property 'includes' does not exist on type 'string[]'.ts(2339)

I am trying to understand as to why I am getting this error, and found out that these two are both object prototype methods. Is there something I am doing wrong syntactically?

Please advise.

Comment: For the first error, you probably need to add an ambiant file to declare the function. For the second error, it is a matter of ECMAScript version. Check the `lib` entry configured in your `tsconfig.json`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to have `includes` on your Arrays you need to modify your tsconfig:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": [
       "dom",
       "es7"
    ]
  }
}
```

To have your custom `isSubsetOf` function available on the global Array prototype, you have to explicitly add the types:

```
interface Array<T> {
  isSubsetOf(arr: T[]): boolean;
}
```

Or globally:

```
declare global {
  interface Array<T> {
    isSubsetOf(arr: T[]): boolean;
  }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIJSnAngHgCoB8yA3gFDLLADOAygK4BGVEYA8jABRwYBcyeAbQC6ASj4MA9hIA2EOCADcpAL6lS6TFgB0ABygSwBrDohbq9Ji3bIAvMhh0QCMMAkhkXDNj5UwUUADmwmLIkjJy7mQUwDAeAITcmlqyIAFgABYiJMjkFMhQLHRQ7n50EEoUqrkFYEUl6dRaEABu0FgcHBDSPn6BIWGy8rZEidhmTtJ0ACYQVJ3SIiJKVQhuvshwtsgCAOSrALb7wGA7ADTIOzp0VOk7QkqkqyBU4ckSAVxmtIzMbJy7ByOJ3OOwKDDgzDOFyuNyhOwY0jg%20wgd0WCmQAHoMchShBSEA)